# Как преобразовать формат даты?

Tags: android

`Datepicker` возвращает дату в формате 18 - мар., а `DateFormat` в формате 18.03. Мне надо сравнить данные полученные из `Datepicker` и из `DateFormat`, для это мне надо написать код для перевода даты из одного формата в другой? Или есть более легкий способ?

Comment: Покажите как Вы получаете обе даты.

Answer (score 0):

Переведите обе даты в миллисекунды. Получите разницу между ними и потом переведите ее в нужный вам формат

Comment: Как мне сделать этот перевод?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637168/how-to-convert-a-date-to-milliseconds